# EXE size bloats while using Websocketpp

Tags: boost, stl, visual-studio-2013, websocket++

I've built a very basic EXE which uses Websocketpp client, which just connects to a Websocket server, and sends and receives a mesage.
I've used VS 2013.

I'm noticing that the size of the EXE is mammoth. It's like 2.3 MB for Release and 6 MB for Debug.

Any ideas as to how I can reduce the size of EXE??

Comment: What is your desired executable size? 6 MB isn't that large these days.

Comment: Hehe. My testrunner is 90MiB

Comment: Well, I agree for a full blown application. But this is just a very basic basic sample.
Well to a point it's understandable, because of use of templates. I mean Websocket++, boost and STL are all template based.
And templates do tend to bloat up the code.

Answer (score 5):

WebSocket++ author here. The sizes you quote seem about the right ballpark. Keep in mind that a "very basic sample" like the echo_server (which produces a ~1MB executable on linux) does a lot more than you might think based on the ~50 lines in the program source.

Out of the box any WebSocket++/Asio based program is a high performance event based client/server system and includes code for DNS resolution, IPv4 and IPv6, timers, SHA1/MD5 hashing, base64 encoding, UTF8 validation, logging, thread safety, and parsers for URIs, HTTP, and multiple WebSocket protocol versions. Just because you only use these capabilities to echo back messages doesn't make this a trivial program.

Some observations/notes on the topic:

1. Due to the way templates work, the code for WebSocket++, ASIO, and the STL is compiled into your program rather than sitting in an externally linked library. This may make a WebSocket++ or Asio program look artificially larger than a program that links to an external library.
2. The situation described in #1 can sometimes end up more efficient than an external library because this program will only include the parts of the library that your code actually uses, rather than all parts. I.e. If you don't instantiate a client endpoint no client code will be included. If your config disables TLS encryption, logging, or the thread safety features they will also not be included. Again due to the way templates work this can go both ways. For example: A program that includes both a client and a server will have some potentially unnecessary duplication.
3. The size of WebSocket++'s code is largely correlated to the number of different endpoint configs that you use and the options enabled in each of those configs. These represent a fixed size no matter what else your program does. If your program does little, they will make up a large proportion of the code. If your program does a lot that proportion will shrink.
4. WebSocket++ is fairly modular (though this is less well documented right now). If you are really concerned about code size (small embedded systems perhaps?) and don't actually need all the features that Asio and WebSocket++ bring out of the box, you can set up a custom config that either removes many features or replaces them with your own space optimized implementations.

   Say you only ever need to service one non-TLS connection with no DNS lookup and no security timeouts in a guaranteed single threaded program with no logging. You can implement your own network transport policy based on your native OS socket library that doesn't include all the stuff that Asio does. You can also stub out the locking/concurrency and logger policies you don't need.